# Spring Tools Suite STS se cierra de la nada?

Tags: java, spring, ide, spring-tool-suite, jvm

Tengo desde hace unos días que el STS se cierra solo cuando estoy trabajando en él y a veces al iniciar el programa ni siquiera logra abrirse.

Cuando se cierra el STS crea un archivo en su ruta de instalación el cuál según dice el problema pero no logro entender qué es. Aquí dejo dicho contenido del archivo:

```
        #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000620b6f9b, pid=7088, tid=0x0000000000002bb8
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0x466f9b]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x0000000015949000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11192, stack(0x00000000160c0000,0x00000000161c0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000069cc1bb0

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000349a6110, RCX=0x00000000161bcc00, RDX=0x0000000010000000
    RSP=0x00000000161bc780, RBP=0x00000000161bc7e0, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00000000161bcc00
    R8 =0x0000000029cc1bb0, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000000
    R12=0x00000000349a6110, R13=0x0000000000007535, R14=0x0000000061c50000, R15=0x0000000000000000
    RIP=0x00000000620b6f9b, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000161bc780)
    0x00000000161bc780:   00000000347ba190 00000000349a6110
    0x00000000161bc790:   00000000161bcc00 00000000161bc910
    0x00000000161bc7a0:   00000e8f00000000 0000000000000008
    0x00000000161bc7b0:   000000001c5af440 0000000000000001
    0x00000000161bc7c0:   000000003599ab18 0000000000000001
    0x00000000161bc7d0:   0000000034841af0 000000001add5bb0
    0x00000000161bc7e0:   ffffffffffffffff 0000000000000000
    0x00000000161bc7f0:   00000000161bcc00 00000000620b7387
    0x00000000161bc800:   00000000349a6110 00000000349a6110
    0x00000000161bc810:   0000000000091c80 0000000000091c80
    0x00000000161bc820:   00000e8f00000000 0000000000000008
    0x00000000161bc830:   000000001c5af440 0000000000000001
    0x00000000161bc840:   000000003599ab18 0000000000000001
    0x00000000161bc850:   0000000034841af0 0000000000000000
    0x00000000161bc860:   0000000020022b68 0000000000000000
    0x00000000161bc870:   00000000000003d8 0000000020022790 

    Instructions: (pc=0x00000000620b6f9b)
    0x00000000620b6f7b:   ca 41 23 c9 3b ca 0f 85 4b ff ff ff 41 8b c1 e9
    0x00000000620b6f8b:   11 02 00 00 49 63 54 24 24 4c 8b 87 08 01 00 00
    0x00000000620b6f9b:   41 8b 1c 90 3b da 74 33 8b cb 48 63 c3 41 8b 1c
    0x00000000620b6fab:   80 3b d9 75 f3 3b d3 74 20 66 66 66 66 0f 1f 84 


    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RBX=0x00000000349a6110 is an unknown value
    RCX=0x00000000161bcc00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015949000
    RDX=0x0000000010000000 is an unknown value
    RSP=0x00000000161bc780 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015949000
    RBP=0x00000000161bc7e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015949000
    RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RDI=0x00000000161bcc00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000015949000
    R8 =0x0000000029cc1bb0 is an unknown value
    R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    R12=0x00000000349a6110 is an unknown value
    R13=0x0000000000007535 is an unknown value
    R14=0x0000000061c50000 is an unknown value
    R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x00000000160c0000,0x00000000161c0000],  sp=0x00000000161bc780,  free space=1009k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0x466f9b]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x467387]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x468d1c]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x4740fb]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x476a07]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x459422]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xa5be2]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xa651f]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x244adf]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x29c3ea]
    C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21d9f]
    C  [MSVCR100.dll+0x21e3b]
    C  [kernel32.dll+0x159cd]
    C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a561]


    Current CompileTask:
    C2: 565576 30441   !   4       org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader::<init> (1583 bytes)


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x000000001fd2f000 JavaThread "Worker-22" [_thread_blocked, id=10796, stack(0x000000002f020000,0x000000002f120000)]
      0x000000001fd2a800 JavaThread "Worker-21" [_thread_in_native, id=5548, stack(0x000000002d100000,0x000000002d200000)]
      0x000000001fd2c000 JavaThread "Worker-20" [_thread_blocked, id=10556, stack(0x000000002b780000,0x000000002b880000)]
      0x000000001b287800 JavaThread "Worker-19" [_thread_in_native, id=9260, stack(0x000000002b580000,0x000000002b680000)]
      0x0000000019df1800 JavaThread "Worker-18" [_thread_blocked, id=4704, 
................. //Más cosas que no creo que sean útiles

Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\sunmscapi.dll
    0x000007fefa980000 - 0x000007fefa987000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
    0x000007fefb0d0000 - 0x000007fefb1fc000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
    0x000007fef6b70000 - 0x000007fef6c95000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 
    java_command: <unknown>
    java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files (x86)\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
    Launcher Type: generic

    Environment Variables:
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
    PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\lib;C:\Bitnami\subversion-1.8.16-0\subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.81\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.4.RELEASE;
    USERNAME=XMY0007
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23889)

    CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

    Memory: 4k page, physical 16685572k(6247908k free), swap 33369284k(22280616k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_151-b12), built on Sep  5 2017 19:33:46 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

    time: Tue Feb 13 16:25:04 2018
    elapsed time: 565 seconds (0d 0h 9m 25s)
```

En un principio investigué y pensé que sería problema de memoria y se la expandí y las configuraciones que tiene ahora el STS.ini son estas:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Alguien sabe por qué se cierra el IDE inesperadamente y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Desconozco lo que te esta pasando, pero este programa tambien lo uso yo. Mi sugerencia es que bajes la version mas reciente o sino bajate Oxygen de eclipse que es muy potente y le descargas el plugin de STS....te lo recomiendo.

Comment: Solo para comentar, no sé si el cierre de STS inesperado se deba a eso pero el DD estaba ya mal. Comenzaron a dar unos pantallazos azules, ahora en esta nueva computadora estoy trabajando normalmente con STS. Puede ser que el problema de que se cerraba solo el STS tenga que ver con fallo en hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás viendo amigo es un error de tu JRE, como verás en la traza te dice que el error está en el archivo `jvm.dll`.

En esos casos lo ideal es reportar el error directamente a Oracle [en la liga que sugiere tu mismo log](http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp); normalmente tardan hasta dos días hábiles en darte soporte, es decir, identificar la causa del problema y derivarlo hacia el desarrollador que lo solucionará.
Este proceso es totalmente gratis para tí, pero si eres un cliente de Oracle de los que pagan por el JDK, podrías tener el problema resuelto mucho antes.

Como puedes ver en el log también, el hilo que falló fue el del compilador.

Finalmente, la versión que usas para correr tu código es `1.8.0_151-b12`, es decir la `1.8.0_151` con el `build`(o parche) número 12, los build son consecutivos, normalmente como resultado de resolver tu problema resportado en Oracle se agregará la solución al siguiente *build*.

Existen versiones mucho más recientes del JRE, te recomiendo actualizar, todos los JRE te permiten la retrocompatibilidad, es decir pueden ejecutar código generado para versiones anteriores, así que no deberías de tener inconveniente.
Posiblemente tu problema se solucionó al cambiar de equipo porque le instalaron la versión siguiente que ya tenía el error corregido.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que a mucha gente le funciona, incluyendome a mí, para este tipo de error es añadir la siguiente linea al `sts.ini` o `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Y retirar la que tienes actualmente:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Comment: Buen día, Miguel, esa configuración la tenía antes de intentar mil y una maneras para arreglar el problema Anteriormente el STS no se iniciaba, cambié mi .ini por dicha configuración que mencionas y ya lo hacia correctamente, pero esta vez era un problema diferente, parece que el hardware era el dañado y de alguna manera intervenía. Me han cambiado de equipo y asunto arreglado xD!